# Add multiple values to .compactMap (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have the following code to present my array in a UITableView:

```
  let obj: SearchResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(SearchResponse.self, from: data)
  let searchObj: [SearchObject]? = obj.ResultSet?.Result?.compactMap { $0.symbol }.map (SearchObject.init)
  self.search_object = searchObj ?? []
```

But, how do I add another string to this? For example, I would like to add the value of $0.name.

```
let obj: SearchResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(SearchResponse.self, from: data)
      let searchObj: [SearchObject]? = obj.ResultSet?.Result?.compactMap { $0.symbol $0.name }.map (SearchObject.init)
      self.search_object = searchObj ?? []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really feel like you have too many optionals, and you're not using casing conventions, which will bite you when you want to make instances of types, but, use a tuple. You also don't need explicit typing.

```swift
let searchObj = obj.ResultSet?.Result?.compactMap { ($0.symbol, $0.name) }.map (SearchObject.init)
```

You also have no reason to run a map/compactMap twice.

```swift
let searchObj = obj.ResultSet?.Result?.compactMap { SearchObject($0.symbol, $0.name) }
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.